# Issue with React-Testing-Library in codesandbox.io

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, codesandbox

I am a relative noob to React. Wanted to practice some tdd in this sandbox [basic react sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/93yp98knx4). It seems that the test code is affecting app component state
If you switch between Browser and Tests you'll see test items being added to the list - even though i am running render and cleanup in the tests.

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Codesandbox has some problems running the tests. That's because they run in the browser and not in a separate jsdom environment. I suggest you run the tests in your machine instead.

Comment: Thank you, BTW CodeSandbox works fine when using Enzyme here's another sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/6nwj46qwn3

Comment: I think it's because Enzyme mocks the rendered components while RTL tries to make a real render

Comment: Right,  shallow vs render - another thing could be the RTL getByTestId which I have been using since the data-testId attribute exists in the app output it matches the real one first. Funny thing is the creator of RTL had a youtube video where he experienced the same issue https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCR3JAR7CHE