# react-testing-library cleanup doesn't work in codesandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, codesandbox

`cleanup` doesn't work in codesandbox and I comment the ReactDOM.render function as someone suggesting to in here: https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client/issues/1525 and it works, but `fireEvent` doesn't work. Vice versa, when I don't comment the ReactDOM.render function, `fireEvent` works and `cleanup` doesn't.

code: https://codesandbox.io/s/mqm2w49y1x

Comment: I personally use enzyme for testing events https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/simulate.html - I know the question is about react-testing-library, but I trully recomend it.

Comment: I would check first if getByText returns what you want - you can console.log this. I'm not sure but it looks like `<BUTTON class="bar-button" style="display: block;">Nurhadi - Aldo</BUTTON>` don't have onClick function at all, so nothing happens.

Comment: @Zydnar I don't know why is that happening, but if we uncomment the ReactDOM.render function, the fireEvent get triggered

Comment: Maybe as workaround create separate test, where you don't import ReactDOM?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue with React-Testing-Library in codesandbox.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387122/issue-with-react-testing-library-in-codesandbox-io)

Comment: fireEvent seems to work for me without `ReactDOM.render`. https://codesandbox.io/embed/o93q230lz9

Answer (score 0):

RTL doesn't work well in codesandbox. Run your tests in your local machine instead.

Comment: No, just `react-testing-library`