# Test is failing as the object is incorrect in React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, testing-library

**Component to test** -

```
import { useState } from "react";

const UserForm = ({ onUserAdd }) => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    onUserAdd({ name, email });
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Email</label>
        <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
      </div>
      <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Add User</button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default UserForm;
```

**Failing Test Case** -

```
test("it calls onUserAdd when the form is submitted", async () => {
  // BETTER IMPLEMENTATION
  const mock = jest.fn();

  // Render - the component
  render(<UserForm onUserAdd={mock} />);

  // Find 2 inputs (name, email in this case)
  const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole("textbox");

  // Simulate typing in a name
  await user.click(nameInput);
  await user.keyboard("jane");

  // Simulate typing in a email
  await user.click(emailInput);
  await user.keyboard("abc@abc.com");

  // Find the submit button
  const button = screen.getByRole("button");

  // Simulate clicking the submit button
  await user.click(button);

  // Assertion - make sure 'onUserAdd' gets called with name/email
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: "jane", email: "abc@abc.com" });
});
```

**Error -**

```
- Expected
+ Received

  Object {
-   "email": "abc@abc.com",
-   "name": "jane",
+   "email": "",
+   "name": "",
  },
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong here.

**Codesandbox Link** - https://codesandbox.io/s/morning-microservice-xxh0mw?file=/src/UserForm.test.js

**PS -** Since I am learning react testing, I used `await` for every event, let me know if this is a correct approach as well. Thanks.

Comment: Codesandbox [has issues with react test library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55387122/issue-with-react-testing-library-in-codesandbox-io). Have you tried just running this on your machine?

Comment: As an aside, it will help you to add `htmlFor` to your Labels and an `id` to your inputs, then use screen.getByLabelText in order to better target individual boxes for testing. Bonus points is that it's better for accessibility too.  Be sure to [setup](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/setup/) for the user events first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally looks ok but I find CodeSandbox to be really buggy when dealing with react testing library.
I replaced your `user.click`s and `user.keyboard`s with **[`user.type`](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/utility#type)** which I find more human readable and concise to work with and it seems to work:

```
test("it calls onUserAdd when the form is submitted", async () => {
  const mock = jest.fn();

  // Render - the component
  render(<UserForm onUserAdd={mock} />);

  // Find 2 inputs (name, email in this case)
  const [nameInput, emailInput] = screen.getAllByRole("textbox");

  // Simulate typing in a name
  await user.type(nameInput, "jane"); // <--here-<<

  // Simulate typing in a email
  await user.type(emailInput, "abc@abc.com"); // <--and here-<<

  // Find the submit button
  const button = screen.getByRole("button");

  // Simulate clicking the submit button
  await user.click(button);

  // Assertion - make sure 'onUserAdd' gets called with name/email
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalled();
  expect(mock).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: "jane", email: "abc@abc.com" });
});
```

And yes, you are correct wo `await` every user action. Although RTL docs recommend to use [**the new setup**](https://testing-library.com/docs/user-event/setup#starting-a-session-per-setup) `const user = userEvent.setup()` instead of calling the API directly

Comment: This worked ..thanks a lot for highlighting the -ve(s) of using testing library in codesandbox... will try to learn by setting the project in system itself.